# How do I define a new handler in Lombok?

Tags: handler, lombok

I want to add my own handler to Lombok. What is the easiest way to have it found by the system? If I add it into the lombok.jar, that seems to work, but it does seem cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe build lombok.jar with your handler from source https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok ?

Comment: That's, I think, what he meant. There should be an easier way, though. I mean, how do the lombok developers try out changes? Are they rebuilding the lombok.jar every time? After that, are they re-registering it?